# The word "Scepter'd Isle" Kindly confirm

Tags: word-meaning, british-english

I encountered this word at an article and after googling I have come to know this word is Shakepear's play origin.

And I found [**this site.**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/scepter-d-isle), and I found another site, which was explaining that the 'd means the past form of the verb scepter, whose definition is below by Merriam.

> or British scep·tre
>   scep·tered or British scep·tred; sceptered or British sceptred; scep·ter·ing or British scep·tring; scep·ters or British scep·tres
>   1
>   :  to endow with the scepter :  invest with royal authority
>   2
>   :  to ratify by touching with the scepter

So would this (probably) old word, scepter'd isle, be some kind of a noun prasing the royal family and their reign in Britain and consequently be the synonym of praise to the England?

Or ultimately saying, this word would mean the "island under ( (blessed) the U.K's royal family's sovereignty? " Kindly confirm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sceptre is an ornamental staff which is held by the Monarch at the coronation, and represents the just authority of the Monarch as head of state. When she receives the sceptre the Monarch is told,

> Receive the rod of Equity and Mercy. Be so merciful that you be not too remiss; so execute justice that you forget not mercy. Punish the wicked, protect and cherish the just, and lead your people in the way wherein they should go.

So to say Britain is a "sceptur'd isle" is to say that Britain is ruled by equitable and merciful kings and queens.

The expression was probably made up by Shakespeare, and is now only used in some sort of reference to Britain: You can't say (for example) "France is a sceptre'd country" it is only used in the quote from Shakespeare.